# How do I include PHP code inside React app - no ajax

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I need to build React app to contain a server generated (say php) content inside some its child component - is that possible?

Because of some cms specific issues I can not load it through ajax - I need it to be there when loaded HTML from server - it may contain some user-specific output, including JavaScript with some event listeners - it's some kind of forms.

It's like SSR, but on backed the server is not node, for sake of simplicity I wrote php, but some parts there are inacessible, its more like a modular locked proprietary system :( and uses some third-side, complicated modifications, so moving the code outside the app, and then move it back in on load, seems at this moment as very complicated thing to do

I know there is possible to put some php in the template file for webpack, but I need it to be "inside" the root app if that is actually possible? - basically like sometimes there will be:

```
return (
  <>
    <SiteHeader />
    <SiteContent>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<?php echo $data; ?>" }} />
    </SiteContent>
    <SiteFooter />
  </>
);
```

that means i need to :

- get some code kept inside html code generated during build 
  like, for example, `<?php echo "hello"; ?>`, so the content inside the generated html code loads the php code output (file will be stored as php extension file).
- when the code is loaded, it should stay there, not get replace from react, so it does not get replaced for the string `<?php echo...`

I somehow guess it has to do with React.hydrate and dangerouslySetInnerHTML function, but still not found the right way, how to put it together to get it work?

Comment: Try Next.js it will help in all SSR stuff

Comment: tried, see many people hating NextJS, dont understand exactly, curently found some prerender-loader and looking into integrating that to webpack - have to try how prerender only parts that matter to keep source size small - sure i find some way to hide unneeded parts with some default empty contents for the rest